# Как закрыть chrome custom tabs, или как закрыть все activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Ребята, может кто то помочь? У меня проблема с хром табсом, я не могу его закрыть или перекрыть новым activity. Искал инфу в инете, везде писали что если запускать интент с флагом FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, то он удаляет все активити и запускает наш, то есть по логике активити хрома должно закрыться, но он не закрывается. Я еще новичок в андроиде и все эти флаги не очень знаю, по этому могу что то пропустить.

```
final Activity context = this;
connection = new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(final ComponentName name, final CustomTabsClient client) {
        client.warmup(0);
        session = client.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras) {
                super.onNavigationEvent(navigationEvent, extras);
                if ( navigationEvent == NAVIGATION_FINISHED ){
                    System.out.println("0 " + number);
                    if (number == 1){
                        System.out.println("1 "  + number);
                        context.unbindService(connection);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        System.out.println("2");
                    }
                    number++;
                }
            }
        });
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(session);
        CustomTabsIntent intent = builder.build();
        intent.intent.setPackage(CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME);
        intent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(URL));
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    }
};
CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(this, CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME, connection);
```

Comment: вы с какой-то активности переходите в хром таб?

Comment: этот код находится в OnCreate в MainActivity

Comment: то есть вы из главной активности хотите перейти в хром таб, а потом в нее же вернуться?

Comment: Нет, Вы не правильно поняли мой вопрос, перейти в хром табс я то могу, но вот откр активность не могу уже после откр хрома. Не знаю как но хром блочит startActivity() , по идее должен быть переход на мой активити и перекрыть хром, но он не закрывается\перекрывается. Мой код открытие Main2Activity выполняется уже когда откр хром, и не срабатывает хотя у него есть флаг FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP который должен по идее удалять\закрывать все активити

Comment: вы finish пробовали использовать при возврате на главную активность?

Comment: В этом же проблема, я не могу понять как вернутся на глав. активити с хрома, я встате побывал когда открыт хром делать финишь и закрыть прогу программно, но хрому было все равно)

Comment: вот смотрите - когда вы переходите на хром таб, вы не должны закрывать активность, а когда вы захотите вернуться на активность обратно, то просто завершите хром таб, я просто не вижу как именно вы попадаете на хром таб

Comment: А понятно, похоже мой код Вас запутал. Если смотреть как он работает, то у меня сразу с лунчера запускается хром (intent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(URL));) . По логике я не закрываю глав. активити потому что нету  флага на интенте хрома. то есть хром открывается сверху глав. активити. И грубо говоря, я допустим через 5 сек(там по клику) пробую открыть какое то активити со флагом FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Но он не открывается и остается хром. Надеюсь я понятно написал)

Comment: то есть при старте приложения у вас стартуется сразу хром таб? но ведь какая-то активность должна быть стартовой в манифесте по логике... странная у вас система и насколько я вот сейчас знаком с практиками использования хром табов, то его используют из какой-то активности/фрагмента а стартовать табы сразу, это как-то не очень понятно)) попробуйте использовать обычный интент без флагов, и добавьте в манифесте у хром табов если они у вас там есть флаг чтобы история не хранилась

Comment: Я же писал ранее что запускаю его с MainActivity который у меня лаунчер(стартовая активность). И так вот, алгоритм программы, откр main activity патом хром, а вот патом я пытаюсь запустить активити с помощью startActivity() но активность не запускается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕбята, нужно выкл. режим разработчика и все заработает. И если у Вас MIUI то нужно вкл. права Отображать всплывающие окна, когда запущено в фоновом режиме. Так же флаги для intent intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  |
                                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP         |
                                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);